# Reference in foot note in a single line

Tags: beamer, bibentry

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\nobibliography*
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
    @article{Akaike1973,
        Title                    = {Information theory and an extension of the maximum likelihood principle},
        Author                   = {Akaike, Hirotogu},
        Booktitle                = {Selected Papers of Hirotugu Akaike},
        Publisher                = {Springer},
        Year                     = {1973},
        Pages                    = {199--213}
    }   

@Article{Hugh1994,
    author  = {James P. Hughes and Peter Guttorp},
    title   = {A class of stochastic models for relating synoptic atmospheric patterns to regional hydrologic phenomena},
    journal = {Water Resources Research},
    year    = {1994},
    volume  = {30},
    number  = {5},
    pages   = {1535--1546},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Foot note reference}

This is my footnote reference \footnote{\tiny \bibentry{Hugh1994}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{my}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify your objective. Are you looking to create a citation call-out in a footnote, or an entire formatted bib entry?

Comment: For your case, perhaps `\footnote{\rlap{\tiny \bibentry{Akaike1973}}}` is good enough

Comment: Thank you, David. Your suggestion worked. But for a long bib entry, how to handle it in two lines rather than three. I have edited and added a long reference in my post.

Comment: Hi Mico, My purpose is how to add a reference in footnote utilizing the full line instead of broken reference in two or three lines leaving lots of space in each line.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it looks like you are trying to put as much content as possible into each line of each footnote.

You can do this by setting the footnote mark and text font to `\tiny` and increasing the `\hsize` of the text in the footnote.

I also suggest using *1.* rather than the superscript *¹* for a footnote mark if you are using `\tiny` font size since otherwise your superscript will be the same size as the rest of your footnote.

There is also another problem with references. `beamer` (essentially) defines `\newblock` as `\par` which inserts your unwanted line break.

Finally, there is also an unwanted strut added to `beamer`'s `\newblock`, which we can remove.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\nobibliography*
\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@article{Akaike1973,
  Title = {Information theory and an extension of the maximum likelihood principle},
  Author = {Akaike, Hirotogu},
  Booktitle = {Selected Papers of Hirotugu Akaike},
  Publisher = {Springer},
  Year = {1973},
  Pages = {199-213}
}   
@article{Hugh1994,
  author = {James P. Hughes and Peter Guttorp},
  title = {A class of stochastic models for relating synoptic atmospheric patterns to regional hydrologic phenomena},
  journal = {Water Resources Research},
  year = {1994},
  volume = {30},
  number = {5},
  pages = {1535-1546}
}
\end{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt}
\setbeamerfont{footnote mark}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{footnote text}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  {\setlength{\hsize}{330pt}%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}%
   \usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}%
   \hspace*{1.5em}%
   \@thefnmark.~%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote text}%
   \usebeamerfont*{footnote text}%
   \insertfootnotetext\par}}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry article}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\def\beamer@newblock{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}%
  \def\newblock{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}%
    \def\newblock{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}%
      \def\newblock{%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Foot note reference}
This is my footnote reference \footnote{\bibentry{Hugh1994}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{my}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That's great. This is what I want. But it is not working for a reference in a footnote. A long reference is still broken in the midway of a line and goes to the next line. Could you please further suggest something?

Comment: @Hooria, Oh! I see what you mean. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect. It is really I wanted. But when I use your suggestions in my original file, it is printing `thefnmark' at the start of reference instead of 1 and `default' before journal name. I request to please help a bit more in this regard.

Comment: @Hooria, oops. Try now. I forgot to fix a copy/paste error.

Comment: Hi David....Just one step far--the code is now only printing 'thefnmark' at the start of reference instead of 1. Could you please help a bit more ?

Comment: @Hooria, have you got `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around (especially) `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{....}` and `\def\beamer@newblock{...}`?

Comment: Hi David...Got it what I wanted. Thank you so very much. :) :) :)